# How can i add an app in android firmware?

Tags: android, firmware

I am having my firmware and I want to change the default launcher and start up logo of the phone? where should I add my .apk file and animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Logo tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1953726) you change the start-up logo by changing the bootaniamtion.zip in firmware with this tool.

Comment: Great ..this what i needed ..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

All apk after installation goes to data/data folder, your launcher if registered to call event will come as one of the option to end user, if your launcher is the only launcher in your firmware, then by default ur launcher will be picked up.

By adding the categories android.intent.category.HOME and android.intent.category.DEFAULT to the intent-filter group, the associated Activity behaves like a launcher and shows up as an option when you press the device's home button

You just need to install apk , it doesn't matter from where you install it.

More details about how you can develop launcer
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358

Comment: thanks Ashish ,..if i delete the default launcher of device and install my launcher..will it work?

Comment: and how can i change the startup logo..?